# How to simplify a fraction like this one?

Tags: factoring

$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x-3}$$

Is there a rule for factorizing polynomials in the numerator?

Comment: @User3711671 Is the numerator factorable? If so, is denominator one of the numerator's factors? Is this question part of a larger question?

Comment: Well i need to do something with this fraction to solve an inequality (this fraction has to be greater than zero).

Comment: use the quadratic formula to see if it can be factored.

Comment: We never mentioned something like a 'quadratic formula' and I think that we won't even mention it for a long time so i think that there has to be another way, also keep in mind that this is for the 1st grade of high school (it's just revision of elementary school mathematics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Simplification" may depend on each one, but

$$\frac{x^2-3x+1}{x-3}=\frac{x(x-3)+1}{x-3}=x+\frac1{x-3}$$

We did "not" simplify by factoring since the factoring of the numerator isn't nice at all in regards with this problem, as the numerator's roots are $\;\frac12\left(3\pm\sqrt5\right)\;$, yet for some use the rightmost expression could probably called "simpler" than the original one. For example, to differentiate the expression or to find the limit when $\;x\to\infty\;$ , etc.

Answer (score 0):

alright, i will complete the squares and use the difference of squares to factor. there is no way you can solve the inequality without factoring.

$$x^2 - 3x + 1 = x^2 - 3x + \frac 94 - \frac 94 + 1=\left(x-\frac32\right)^2 -\left(\frac {\sqrt 5} 2\right)^2 = \left(x -\frac{3-\sqrt 5}2\right)\left(x -\frac{3+\sqrt 5}2\right) $$  therefore you want solve
$$\frac{ \left(x -\frac{3-\sqrt 5}2\right)\left(x -\frac{3+\sqrt 5}2\right)}{(x-3)} > 0 $$ has the three critical numbers $x = {(3-\sqrt5)}/2, 3, {(3-\sqrt5)}/2$ and switches across each. and you can verify by taking one test point in each of the region, if you must, that the solution is $${(3 -\sqrt 5)}/2 < x < 3, {(3 +\sqrt 5)}/2 < x < \infty. $$

Comment: Why did you decide the OP wanted to solve an inequality and why precisely that *one* ??

Comment: @Timbuc, you don't read his response in the comments? don't go telling me what i can and cannot do.

Comment: I would never dream of telling you what to do and what not to do. And the comments only talk of an inequality, though it indeed says, for some reason, that the expression has to be positive. Don't be that sensitive with people that didn't have any intention neither to hurt you nor to "tell you what to do" (?), not to mention that many people, and I among them, read mainly the question, where all data should be, and *not necessarily* the comments.

Comment: @Timbuc, i use the comment section to get clarification if the question is not clear. that is how i got the op to tell me what problem he was looking to solve.